Docker/NPM - Self-signed certificate in chain issue
My company has a self-signed certificate within our network that I cannot get around. I have added the cert to both my Windows and WSL cert stores and verified they work. However, when I build an image a vendor gave us, something is not respecting the cert stores and I'm having trouble narrowing down what it is and how to resolve it.
Output:
11.62 npm ERR! code 1
11.62 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/iconv
11.62 npm ERR! command failed
11.62 npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp rebuild
11.62 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
11.62 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
11.62 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.20.2 | linux | x64
11.62 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
11.62 npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2-headers.tar.gz
11.62 npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/iconv
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
11.62 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
11.62
11.62 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
11.62 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-05T14_36_30_439Z-debug-0.log

Update 1
I updated the Dockerfile file to copy the crt in and run update-ca-certificates. It says it added 1. However, I still run into the same cert chain issue.
Update 2
I changed my base image from gallium-buster to bullseye so it was more up to date (image, npm, nodejs, etc) and still running into the same issue.
 => ERROR [web dependencies 3/9] RUN update-ca-certificates     && npm install -g npm@latest     && npm set progress=false     && npm config set depth 0     && npm i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       14.5s 
------
 > [web dependencies 3/9] RUN update-ca-certificates     && npm install -g npm@latest     && npm set progress=false     && npm config set depth 0     && npm i:
0.207 Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0.474 1 added, 0 removed; done.
0.474 Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
0.475 done.
4.664
4.664 removed 2 packages, and changed 63 packages in 4s
4.664
4.664 24 packages are looking for funding
4.664   run `npm fund` for details
7.017 npm warn deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
7.308 npm warn deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
7.788 npm warn deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
10.42 npm warn deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
14.32 npm error code 1
14.32 npm error path /app/node_modules/iconv
14.32 npm error command failed
14.32 npm error command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
14.32 npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
14.32 npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
14.32 npm error gyp info using node@22.2.0 | linux | x64
14.32 npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
14.32 npm error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v22.2.0/node-v22.2.0-headers.tar.gz
14.32 npm error gyp http fetch GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v22.2.0/node-v22.2.0-headers.tar.gz attempt 1 failed with SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
14.32 npm error gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! configure error
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v22.2.0/node-v22.2.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack at _destroy (node:_http_client:882:13)
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:902:5)
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/iconv
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! node -v v22.2.0
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
14.32 npm error gyp ERR! not ok
14.32 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-06T13_54_41_250Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c update-ca-certificates     && npm install -g npm@latest     && npm set progress=false     && npm config set depth 0     && npm i" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


So the certificate isn’t added in the docker container itself?

Please don't post images of text; just post the text itself, formatted as a code sample. That makes the question more discoverable and more accessible to people using screen readers or other assistive devices.

@t.niese forgive me if I'm being dense, Docker is not my forte and I'm just kind of getting into it, but I'm not even at running a container. This is building the image to then run on the container. Given the paths in the error message, it looks like the image build is being done on WSL and I have the company's cert added on my WSL. However, I do recognize I'm missing or misunderstanding some context here.

If you build a Dockerfile then all commands happen inside of that image, within the context of the operating system the base image is based on. This system does not know anything of the certification store outside of it. So you have to copy your ca into the container and update the ca store before executing a command that would communicated with the self sign service.

I see. So if I understand this correctly, I'd have to update my Dockerfile to include a step to copy the cert into the image, then run the update-ca-certificates command, then proceed. Am I understanding that correctly?

Yes that’s what I meant. The order in which the commands appear in the dockerfile is essential.
